# Unable to install CEC in Virtualenv with Python 3.4

Tags: pip, cec-client

I am  trying to install CEC `pip install cec` but I am unable to do so. I get the following error:

```
(venv) pi@MyPi3:~/my_projects_pi $ pip install cec
Collecting cec
  Using cached cec-0.2.5.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: cec
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cec ... error
  Complete output from command /home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-x_spz_uj/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpbf7nltz9pip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'cec' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/include/python3.4m -c cec.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/cec.o
  cec.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* set_stream_path(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
  cec.cpp:411:25: error: ‘PyInt_Check’ was not declared in this scope
         if(PyInt_Check(arg)) {
                           ^
  cec.cpp:412:39: error: ‘PyInt_AsLong’ was not declared in this scope
            long arg_l = PyInt_AsLong(arg);
                                         ^
  cec.cpp:420:35: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
         } else if(PyString_Check(arg)) {
                                     ^
  cec.cpp:421:46: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
            char * arg_s = PyString_AsString(arg);
                                                ^
  cec.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* initcec()’:
  cec.cpp:671:7: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
         return;
         ^
  cec.cpp:681:31: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
      if(PyType_Ready(dev) < 0 ) return;
                                 ^
  cec.cpp:683:50: error: ‘Py_InitModule’ was not declared in this scope
      PyObject * m = Py_InitModule("cec", CecMethods);
                                                    ^
  cec.cpp:685:20: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
      if( m == NULL ) return;
                      ^
  error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cec
  Running setup.py clean for cec
Failed to build cec
Installing collected packages: cec
  Running setup.py install for cec ... error
    Complete output from command /home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-x_spz_uj/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-44cdj2l0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/include/site/python3.4/cec:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cec' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/include/python3.4m -c cec.cpp -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/cec.o
    cec.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* set_stream_path(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
    cec.cpp:411:25: error: ‘PyInt_Check’ was not declared in this scope
           if(PyInt_Check(arg)) {
                             ^
    cec.cpp:412:39: error: ‘PyInt_AsLong’ was not declared in this scope
              long arg_l = PyInt_AsLong(arg);
                                           ^
    cec.cpp:420:35: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
           } else if(PyString_Check(arg)) {
                                       ^
    cec.cpp:421:46: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
              char * arg_s = PyString_AsString(arg);
                                                  ^
    cec.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* initcec()’:
    cec.cpp:671:7: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
           return;
           ^
    cec.cpp:681:31: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        if(PyType_Ready(dev) < 0 ) return;
                                   ^
    cec.cpp:683:50: error: ‘Py_InitModule’ was not declared in this scope
        PyObject * m = Py_InitModule("cec", CecMethods);
                                                      ^
    cec.cpp:685:20: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ [-fpermissive]
        if( m == NULL ) return;
                        ^
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-x_spz_uj/cec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-44cdj2l0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/my_projects_pi/venv/include/site/python3.4/cec" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-x_spz_uj/cec/
```

If anyone has seen this and can help me figure this out it would be appreciated.

I am trying to turn my TV on/off using Raspberry Pi 3 but so far this is the last step that is not working. I also installed Python 3.4 in the Virtualenv. It looks like it is unable to build the wheel for cec.